Can't open gnome-terminal on fedora 40
When I open (gnome) terminal, nothing happens, no error no nothing. I've tried uninstalling it and rebooting followed by a reinstall and all the different combinations of that.
I'm able to install and run 'Contour' terminal just fine but I'm not really sure what commands I could run to solve this issue. No disrespect to Contour but I'd like my gnome-terminal to work.
I installed Fedora 40 a few weeks ago fresh and I haven't touched it since then. I think the only thing I did that could have potentially sparked an issue would be that I wanted to change to zsh for my terminal.
I think this was the command I used chsh -s $(which zsh). If memory serves it didn't seem to do anything straight away.
Fedora is the first time I've stepped outside the debian based distros but I did find the program called logs and it does seem to be recording something every time I try to open the terminal.
gnome-terminal-[8638]: segfault at 7fadb2a4fa56 ip 00007faa772039b1 sp 00007ffd2cde1978 error 4 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.8000.3[7faa771d5000+38000] likely on CPU 4 (core 5, socket 0)

I'm not really sure how to proceed. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

If you reinstall gnome-terminal and glib2, does the problem go away?

I don't know why this keeps coming up lately, but, people: if it's always the same operation that fails at the same place it's not failing RAM. The mapping between what a program sees and the physical RAM is essentially random. So, if RAM fails, it's extremely unlikely that things fail in the same place twice. (exception: you do something like uncompressing a huge archive, using a lot of RAM: that's very likely to "find" the bad RAM, and then some checksum might fail.But then you get failures at different points in the decompression,you'd notice. This is clearly not one of these cases)

OK, that looks like a bug. Not sure what causes it – but the first order of the day would be running an update; assuming you can still "check for available updates" via GUI, that should work. If you can't find that, switching to a virtual terminal using Alt+F2 should work; log in there, and run sudo dnf update -y (The -y is for "yes to everything"; since you say you haven't done anything special, at this point it's very unlikely that things go wrong here).
Afterwards, systemctl reboot (or just selecting to reboot your system from the graphical interface) to restart your computer.
You can also install a different terminal emulator to get you working again, sudo dnf install alacritty, for example (or install alacritty through the graphical software manager).

Marcus, in a similar spirit to your rant about failing RAM, my pet peeve is asking to reinstall the software. I have no clue why people keep recommending it. It's basically replacing some files writable by root only with the same contents, plus seldom running some idempotent scripts to update some global stuff. I see no way the regular use of a system could have corrupted these, let alone in a way that causes a systematic segfault, like, a few bytes are corrupted, or what? What's the rationale behind asking to reinstall? Maybe a faulty disk (but then you'd have to address that)?

@egmont fair point! I do agree; this is all not likely! I did have trouble with the gnome-terminal server component that I broke by running a competing service of the same name (an experimental modification), but that was a) "ellbows deep in" and b) a user service that a reinstall wouldn't have fixed.

I'm sorry for any other users coming across this issue but after days of trying different things; some mentioned here and in other places, I caved. I just deleted the whole drive and re-installed Fedora brand new. I was in the fortunate situation of it being a fresh install anyway so starting fresh again was minimal. I don't consider this an actual useful answer to give to someone, but, it did work. As such, I won't be marking my answer as correct. If a moderator feels like it should be that's up to them.
Something that might be of note however is that this time when I did install oh-my-zsh I was presented with the option

make zsh the default

Or something to that effect. Now that question was likely asked of me before and I likely did say yes to it as well. But this time I rebooted straight after that and saw that my gnome-terminal opened fine and with zsh as the default. I do believe that something I did when trying to force zsh to be the default without realising a reboot was all that was needed, is where my issue was likely created.
